# What is moving window strategy?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, data-analysis

I searched on google but I couldn't find appropriate information. I am studying curve fitting and I guess it is related issue. However I don't have any idea about it. Can you explain briefly?

Answer (score 3):

I think it refers to the [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average), possibly with a weight. It is used, for example, in [Curve Fitting Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smoothing-data.html) in Matlab: if you scroll down the page, you will see several examples. Here is [another one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Convolution_of_spiky_function_with_box2.gif), from Wikipedia article on convolution (of which the moving average is a special case).

[image: moving average]